What does this dimension mean?
I am creating a circuit board and I need to incorporate a battery holder. However I can not for the life of me understand what these dimensions mean on the slotted holes in the recommended PCB layout. They claim they want the dimensions for this hole to be (2-1.4x0.6). I can't find this format online I would assume the 2 would be the length of the slot but that doesn't seem to account for the 0.3mm tolerance of lead that will go through the hole am I just supposed to account for this myself?
I can just make the hole bigger than the lead but I am trying to understand what this drawing is trying to convey.


The "2" in this case means two/both holes shown on either side of the footprint have dimensions of 1.4x0.6mm.
I hypothesize that this dimension (and the corresponding terminal) are specifically called out in this way because it would be a logical move to make one of the legs wider than the other to prevent installing the battery holder in the wrong direction. Not, obviously, because of any polarity concerns, but because the battery can only be inserted from one side. I have had to desolder and flip coin cell holders before because of this.

Ok thank you! That makes way more sense that means I was also reading the size of the lead wrong. With this logic the lead is actually 1mm wide and the 2 just means that there are two of them.

The slot is 1.4x0.6mm and there are two of them.
Normally it would be "2x 1.4x0.6mm" but I suspect they wanted to avoid ambiguity of multiple x.
https://www.mcgill.ca/engineeringdesign/step-step-design-process/basics-graphics-communication/principles-dimensioning
